# Optimizing database one table or more

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-optimization

I'm working on database design for questionnaire system
and there will be unknown number of answers but less than 6 
so i want to know what is better for performance adding 2 table and use join to query them 
or one table with null answer ? 
[First Approch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR9nv.png)

[Second Approch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TNNq.png)

Comment: Are your answers free text or some selection in preset group?

Comment: answers can be many types including both you mentioned

Comment: Ok do you need to do SQL query searches based on these answers?  Ex. question 1 has 3 possible answers.  Answer1, Answer2, Answer3.  So do you need to do an SQL ... WHERE question1 = 'Answer1' ?